# How to parse this type of dictionary?

Tags: json, swift, parsing, dictionary

How to parse "interestpolls" dictionary, I want to append this poll_id in array.

I was trying by this way but it's not been working; suggest the way for parsing this dictionary.

```
if let result = JSON?["result"] as? String
                    {
                        if result == "success"
                        {
                                if let n=JSON?["interestpolls"] as? [String:Any]
                                {

//parsing code
}
}
}
```

How to parse this dictionary in Swift:

```
 {
      "result": "success",
      "err_message": "Polls found successfully",
      "err_code": "E100",
      "interestpolls": [
        {
          "rank": 4,
          "poll_id": 49,
          "poll_text": "Video Image Poll ?",
          "poll_type": "S",
          "user_id_creator": 29,
          "user_full_name": "Sam",
          "profile_pic": "https://pollyscrackers.s3.amazonaws.com/users/profile_pic_29_1503498846.jpg",
          "poll_visibility": "W",
          "dt_created": 1503988510696,
          "poll_media_url": "https://pollyscrackers.s3.amazonaws.com/polls/poll_49_1503988510.jpg",
          "poll_results": {
            "poll_results_vote_based": {
              "totalvotes": 3,
              "Yes": 3,
              "No": 0
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "rank": 1,
          "poll_id": 6,
          "poll_text": "New Poll",
          "poll_type": "S",
          "user_id_creator": 10,
          "user_full_name": "Mohan Roy vaghela",
          "profile_pic": "https://pollyscrackers.s3.amazonaws.com/users/profile_pic_10_1504077441.gif",
          "poll_visibility": "W",
          "dt_created": 1501746922046,
          "poll_media_url": "https://pollyscrackers.s3.amazonaws.com/polls/poll_6_1501746922.jpg",
          "poll_results": {
            "poll_results_vote_based": {
              "totalvotes": 14,
              "Answer1": 7,
              "Answer2": 6
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "rank": 2,
          "poll_id": 28,
          "poll_text": "What is the way to become enterprenur",
          "poll_type": "S",
          "user_id_creator": 1,
          "user_full_name": "Akshay",
          "profile_pic": "https://pollyscrackers.s3.amazonaws.com/users/profile_pic_1_1504503078.jpg",
          "poll_visibility": "W",
          "dt_created": 1501746922046,
          "poll_media_url": "https://pollyscrackers.s3.amazonaws.com/polls/poll_8_1502198168.jpg",
          "poll_results": {
            "poll_results_vote_based": {
              "totalvotes": 4,
              "Startup with job": 1,
              "Startup without job": 3
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "rank": 3,
          "poll_id": 29,
          "poll_text": "Who is best prgrammer in world",
          "poll_type": "S",
          "user_id_creator": 1,
          "user_full_name": "Akshay",
          "profile_pic": "https://pollyscrackers.s3.amazonaws.com/users/profile_pic_1_1504503078.jpg",
          "poll_visibility": "W",
          "dt_created": 1501746922046,
          "poll_media_url": "https://pollyscrackers.s3.amazonaws.com/polls/poll_8_1502198168.jpg",
          "poll_results": {
            "poll_results_vote_based": {
              "totalvotes": 4,
              "AKS": 2,
              "SASK": 2
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: `interestpolls` would need to be casted as an array... `["interestpolls"] as? [[String:Any]]`

Answer (score 1):

You are casting it as interest polls as Dictionary, cast it as an array. Try the following code.

```
var pollIDList = [String]()

if let result = JSON?["result"] as? String {
  if result == "success" {
    let array = JSON?["interestpolls"] as? Array
    pollIDList.append(array["poll_id"])
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
    if let result = JSON?["result"] as? String
{
    if result == "success"
    {
        if let n=JSON?["interestpolls"] as? [[String:Any]]
        {
            for data in n {
                if let id = data["poll_id"] as? String {
                    self.pollIDList.append(id)
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As "as diu" points out, your interestpolls key/value pair contains an array, not a dictionary.

Another point is that you can create a complex if statement rather than nesting a whole bunch of `if`s:

```
if let result = JSON?["result"] as? String,
  result == "success",
  let  polls = JSON?["interestpolls"] as? [[String: Any]] {
    for aPollDict in polls {
      //your code to parse a poll here
    }
}
```

Comment: that is an elegant solution without using multiple `if`s. Good one!